# How to use join table to retrieve data?

Tags: mysql

I have Table A to store code and Table B to store item details

```
TableA                    TableB
--------------------       -------------------------------------
 code_id  code_name         item_id  item_name  code_1   code_2
--------------------       -------------------------------------
    1       AAA                1       apple      1        2
    2       BBB                2       orange     1        1      
--------------------       -------------------------------------

Dim query as String = "SELECT item_name, TableA.code_name 
                       FROM TableB
                       LEFT JOIN TableA
                       ON TableB.code_1 = TableA.code_id
                       WHERE item_name = apple"

Result
-----------------------
item_name  code_name
-----------------------
 apple        AAA
-----------------------
```

Above query will only return one code name, how if I want to retrieve code_1 and code_2?

```
Result that I want
----------------------------
 item_name  code_1   code_2
----------------------------
  apple      AAA      BBB
----------------------------
```

Comment: What if you add a third code??

Comment: @vbnewbie You only joined to code_1 field, You need to join code_2 as well.

Comment: @JanWalczak how to join code_2? Select item_name, TableA.code_name AS 'code_1', TableA.code_name AS 'code_2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify in your SELECT what columns you want to retrive

```
SELECT item_name, A.code_name, B.code_name FROM TableB WHERE item_name = 'apple'
LEFT JOIN TableA A ON TableB.code_1 = TableA.code_id 
LEFT JOIN TableA B ON TableB.code_2 = TableA.code_id
```

Comment: the result become apple,AAA,1,2, How can I get apple,AAA,BBB instead of  the code_id?

Comment: but the structure of your tables are not quite right. You should only have 'code' in table B, and use pivot to retrieve columns instead of rows. What will you do when a new code_name will be needed? Add a new column code_3?

Comment: I think that is only 2 column will need to retrieve data from TableA, and thank for the answer!

Comment: No problem, I also had a similar problem and now I have to recreate the database because I thought I won't need a new column

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT S1.item_name, U.code_name
    FROM tableA U
    JOIN tableB S1 ON (S1.code_1 = U.code_id)
    JOIN tableB S2 ON (S2.code_2 = U.code_id)
 WHERE item_name = apple"
```